# How do I verify that my hosting provider gave me SSDs?

Tags: vps, ssd

I searched and found 2 options, none of which I'm confident provided me the answer.

1: `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational`

This output '1' to stdout.  What does this mean?

2: `lshw -class disc`

but couldn't find anything that answers my question.

Comment: Is this a VPS or bare metal?

Comment: its VPS and i have root access

Comment: The [honor system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_system).

Comment: @MDMoore313: Exactly. Quite frankly, if I had reason to even suspect my hoster would try to fool me like that, I would switch away immediately.

Comment: This is *not* a technical problem...

Comment: isn't [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65595/44425) contains so many ways for you to check? The most reliable one is checking the disk model if it's SSD or not

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's try to read 1000 random 4k blocks from first 16GB of a disk:

```
time for i in `seq 1 1000`; do
    dd bs=4k if=/dev/sda count=1 skip=$(( $RANDOM * 128 )) >/dev/null 2>&1;
done
```

This is something that should be very slow on rotating drive in comparison with SSD. On my desktop class SSD it ends in about a second. On desktop class 7200rpm rotating drive it ends in 10 seconds.

Comment: thank I got these respone:   `real    0m1.632s user    0m0.336s sys     0m0.939s` it mean i am on ssd?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are.

Comment: on my VM whose virtual disk is placed on an HDD it takes only ~1.5s to complete this so it's not correct

Comment: You might need to make sure that you have data there. Unused space on a VM volume might be using sparse files or equivalent technology - that would fool this check. Also if there are like 10+ drives in RAID behind this, which would share load, then it's not that easy to distinguish it from single SSD.

Comment: That hides all errors :D So you can measure error reporting time: `dd: failed to open ‘/dev/sdb’: Permission denied`

Answer (score 4):

In a physical machine (not a VPS), you can get the type with `smartctl`:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

and grep for `Rotation`:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Rotation
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device

smartctl -a /dev/sdb | grep Rotation
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
```

It's quite likely you have no chance to identify the disk type inside a VPS, as the hypervisor abstracts the real hardware away from the guest machines.

Comment: there is nothing i can install for exmaple that will check the write speed or something? becuose i am afraid that he gave me normal hd when he promised for ssd

Comment: It's somewhat difficult inside a VPS because there are many factors affecting the disk speed, but at least the access times *should* be significantly better with a SSD as compared to normal disks. Try `bonnie++` etc.

Comment: @amirbar you have to remember also that your VPS could be distributed amongst *several* drives and/or CPUs, I wouldn't worry too much about physical hardware as I would *actual performance* of the service you're trying to run on the VPS. SSDs are nice but not necessarily a requirement for *most* services.